# Does anyone have a good video tutorial for tying Tzitzit knots?

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-katan, tying-knots-kosheir

I'm curious if anyone has a good video tutorial for correctly tying Tzizit knots.

My main issue is the resources I've found on the subject have either not been explained in a clear enough way or they have been produced by fake Jewish (**Messianic**) sources. I have no idea why they seem to have cornered the market on this specific subject but most of the video tutorials I've found for Tzitzit have been produced by Messianic sources.

Because of this, I can't allow myself to take the sources as being correct or legitimate. I'd be too concerned about something being explained in a way which subjectively forces Christ symbolism into my knots.

Any suggestions for genuine sources would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: http://tekhelet.com/tekhelet-tying-tools/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mois Navon of the Ptil Tekhelet Organization offers video tutorials via [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/mnavon) for tying the various methods of tzitzit with techelet.

For tying tzitzit without techelet, please see these videos:

[Yemenite/Temani/Rambam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-B1p9dipyaA)

[Sephardi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8jzP7hCwE)

[Ashkenazi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FehK2VPVlWE)

[Arizal/Chabad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr_kgBlyrs4)

Hope this helps. Please note that all of these videos come from Orthodox, non-Messianic sources.

Comment: By the way, I have been wanting to make some tzitzit-tying tutorial videos for some time now. I am quite fluent in the tying of most if not all methods, and it would be a really fun thing to do.

Comment: when you make this please post it

Comment: I said I wanted to make one, not that I was in the process of making one, but OK. I zikher will post it here if I make one. What do you think of the videos I provided?

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: @TheSicilianJew - If you like an answer consider marking it accepted.