# Shamash needs to be a little longer than the rest of the strings?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, shiurim-measurements

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78884/603), @Ezra linked to video tutorials of different methods of tying tzitzit.

In the [Arizal/Chabad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr_kgBlyrs4) method, the tutor says that according to Halacha, once the tying of the tzitzit is completed, the shamash should stick out a little longer than the rest of the strings.

What is the source for this?

Comment: I searched endlessly for something in the Shulchan Aruch HaRav, but only to find it just isn't in there. http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3269361/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-11-Laws-Relating-to-Threads-of-Tzitzis.htm

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing,in fact ,I have heard the exact opposite that after one ties if one sees the shamash is longer the can cut it to size with their teeth,it seems maybe the person in the vid extended the idea of having a long shamash in the first place,but who knows